# Graph edges absent in the route code while using the osmnx package

Tags: python, gis, analytics, automatic-ref-counting, osmnx

I have  error as follows 'ValueError : Graph contains no edges'. I am using the code from an article from towards datascience which talks about finding routes between points.I have followed the exact procedure as mentioned with changes to code according to latest documentation of osmnx package. The link: https://towardsdatascience.com/visualization-in-python-finding-routes-between-points-2d97d4881996

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)
# define the start and end locations in latlng
start_latlng = (37.78497,-122.43327)
end_latlng = (37.78071,-122.41445)
# location where you want to find your route
place     = 'San Francisco, California, United States'
# find shortest route based on the mode of travel
mode      = 'walk'        # 'drive', 'bike', 'walk'
# find shortest path based on distance or time
optimizer = 'time'        # 'length','time'
# create graph from OSM within the boundaries of some 
# geocodable place(s)
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type = mode)
# find the nearest node to the start location
orig_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(graph,37.78497,-122.43327 )
# find the nearest node to the end location
dest_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(graph,37.78071,-122.41445)
#  find the shortest path
shortest_route = nx.shortest_path(graph,
                                  orig_node,
                                  dest_node,
                                  weight=optimizer)
shortest_route_map = ox.plot_route_folium(graph, shortest_route)
shortest_route_map
```

Error shown :

```
ValueError: graph contains no edges
```

Comment: You have swapped the X and Y arguments when you search for nearest_nodes https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.nearest_nodes

Comment: Also you do not appear to add a time attribute to your graph edges, but you are attempting to minimize it.